# How to get intent score/confidence using amazon-lex?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

Luis, watson, dialogflow - all they in json result returns score/confidence value(luis example):

```
"intents": [
{
  "intent": "SearchSigil",
  "score": 0.9916578
},
```

**Is there a way get score using amazon-lex?**

Answer (score 0):

Lex currently does not support this functionality. So there is **no way** of getting the score.

After intent is matched, we get below response from Lex:

```
{
  "currentIntent": {
    "name": "intent-name",
    "slots": {
      "slot name": "value",
      "slot name": "value"
    },
    "slotDetails": {
      "slot name": {
        "resolutions" : [
          { "value": "resolved value" },
          { "value": "resolved value" }
        ],
        "originalValue": "original text"
      },
      "slot name": {
        "resolutions" : [
          { "value": "resolved value" },
          { "value": "resolved value" }
        ],
        "originalValue": "original text"
      }
    },
    "confirmationStatus": "None, Confirmed, or Denied (intent confirmation, if configured)"
  },
  "bot": {
    "name": "bot name",
    "alias": "bot alias",
    "version": "bot version"
  },
  "userId": "User ID specified in the POST request to Amazon Lex.",
  "inputTranscript": "Text used to process the request",
  "invocationSource": "FulfillmentCodeHook or DialogCodeHook",
  "outputDialogMode": "Text or Voice, based on ContentType request header in runtime API request",
  "messageVersion": "1.0",
  "sessionAttributes": { 
     "key": "value",
     "key": "value"
  },
  "requestAttributes": { 
     "key": "value",
     "key": "value"
  }
}
```

Comment: @JayA.Little do you think there is any other hacky way to achieve this